# Linear Algebra: Vector Spaces - Bases and Dimension Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, independence

On the homework I was assigned, I get to a point where it says:

```
"Determine a linearly independent set of vectors that spans the same 
 subspace V as that spanned by the original set of vectors."
```

and then the first problem is has the information:

```
V = ℝ^3, {(3,1,5),(0,0,0),(1,2,-1),(-1,2,3)}.
```

I have to do multiple problems like this, and I have no idea how to do this, so if you could explain this one specifically while also being generic, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: To start with, does $(0,0,0)$ contribute anything to the span? Can any linearly independent set include $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Yeah I shouldn't have picked that one as an example. I quickly found that I can not include the (0,0,0) vector without changing the span, but that doesn't really help me with solving the problems where I can't just leave out one without any work. So, thanks for the response, but can you just give me a generic explanation for these types of problems?

Comment: You want to build a linearly independent "output" set of vectors from the given "input" set. Here is a general procedure that will work. Start with the first vector in the input set. If it is nonzero, add it to the output set. Otherwise, discard it. Then repeat the following: consider the next vector in the input list. Can it be written as a nonzero linear combination of the vectors that are in the output list so far? If not, add it to the output list. Otherwise, discard it. Continue this procedure until every vector in the input list has been either added to the output list or discarded.